# Java Script нужно заменить символы в строке с 7 до 12 на "*"

Tags: javascript

есть номер карты, нужно заменить символы с 7 до 12 включительно на *.
как это можно реализовать?
let card = "4000001234567899"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
let str = "4000001234567899";
console.log(str.slice(0, 7) + '*'.repeat(5) + str.slice(12));
```

если 7 тоже включительно, то будет соответственно

```js
let str = "4000001234567899";
console.log(str.slice(0, 6) + '*'.repeat(6) + str.slice(12));
```

еще вариант:

```js
let str = "4000001234567899"
console.log(str.replace(str.substring(6,12), "*".repeat(6)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let str = "4000001234567899"
console.log(str.replace(/(?<=.{6}).{6}/, '*'.repeat(6)))
```